# Shared Parameters on Test Suite in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

Is there a way to set Shared Parameters in VSTS on a test suite, so that all test cases in the test suite inherit from it and I can use the Shared Parameters on the test suite in every test case in the suite?

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do automatically using normal TFS. You might be able to write a tool to do it, but I have limited experience with the API for Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you create/update a test case in VSTS, you can "Insert Parameters" in the case. After the parameter is inserted, you can click "Convert to shared parameters" link to convert it to a shared parameters. And in other test cases, you can click "Add a shared parameter set" to use the shared parameters. Refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997832.aspx

Comment: But in this case the parameter values are still defined on a task case level. Is it somehow possible to define the value for shared parameters of test cases contained in a test suite on test suite level? 

Eg. I have a parameter Url on two test cases C1 and C2 and two test suites S1 and S2 both containing these two test cases. I would like to define on test suite S1 that parameter Url should be http://foo for both C1 and C2 and on test suite S2 that parameter Url should be http://bar.

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do this for now.